# jQuery UI Selectable: how to get mouse coordinates on 'stop' event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, events, jquery-selectors

I wonder how to get `e.pageX` and `e.pageY` or its analogs on stop event? (in order to show pop up menu for example)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All jQueryUI events provide `event` as a callback argument

```
$( ".selector" ).selectable({
   stop: function(event, ui) {
       alert( event.pageX) ;
   }
});
```

Good learning trick with jQueryUI is to log `event` and `ui` to console on a few events. Especially `ui`. Gives you a good feel for what is available to work with

Answer (score 1):

In the last month I decided I needed a reliable way to check mouse positioning and get mouseover easily with jquery.  Below is the code I use and I think it will solve your issues.

```
    var mouse = {
    mouseX: null,
    mouseY: null,
    init: function() {
        $(document).bind('mousemove', function(event) {
            mouse.mouseX = event.pageX;
            mouse.mouseY = event.pageY;
        });
    },
    isOver: function($element) {
        $elementPosition = $($element).offset();
        $elementWidth = $($element).width();
        $elementHeight = $($element).height();
        $returnValue = true;
        if (mouse.mouseX !== null) {
            if (mouse.mouseX < $elementPosition.left) { $returnValue = false; }
            if (mouse.mouseY < $elementPosition.top) { $returnValue = false; }
            if (mouse.mouseX > $elementPosition.left + $elementWidth) { $returnValue = false; }
            if (mouse.mouseY > $elementPosition.top + $elementHeight) { $returnValue = false; }
        }
        return $returnValue;
    }
}
```

You just need to fire the init on domready then you can get the current mouse coordinates at any time and you can find out if the mouse is over a specific element easily.

```
// Init 
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    mouse.init();
});

//Getting Positions
var mouseX = mouse.mouseX;
var mouseY = mouse.mouseY;

// Determining Mouseover
if (mouse.isOver($('#elementId'))) {
    alert('Is over');
}
```

Comment: Good code but OP was asking how to do it on jQuery UI selectable's stop event.

Answer (score 0):

how about something along these lines?

```
var curX = 0;
var curY = 0;

$(document).mousemove(function(e)
{
  curX = e.pageX; curY = e.pageY;
});

$( ".selector" ).selectable({
   stop: function(event, ui) { console.log(curX+"/"+curY); }
});
```

and also:

```
$(ui).offset()
```

could be interesting to [look at.](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)

Answer (score 0):

Would this help. Just adding on to the other two answers, if you just do console.log(e), you can find lot of information about the event. And going through the information, I found that the pageX and pageY information is stored under originalEvent.

```
                    console.log(e.originalEvent.pageX);
                    console.log(e.originalEvent.pageY);
```

Also, when you select an item, and have your chrome developer tool open and view the element, a div is added with a class of 'ui-selectable-helper', which calculates top and left position of your mouse.